# How to manage Gmail labels in mutt

Tags: gmail, imap, mutt, gmail-imap

Is there a way to manage Gmail lables(Virtual folders) with mutt??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting [this source](http://blitiri.com.ar/p/other/mutt-labels/),

> A very cool gmail feature is the ability to add label to emails (also called "tags" in other contexts), and then view only mails with a given label.
>
> **There is a semi-standard email header called "X-Label" which can be used to store labels. mutt supports searching it, filtering views according to the value, and showing it in the index view;** but it doesn't allow you to change it (although there are patches).

There are some useful code snippets in the link above.